# I want to store 0x0000369c data into 0x000010fc memory address. Is this correct?

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to write  0x0000369c data into 0x000010fc memory address. How can I do that?

```
ldr r4,=0x0000369c    
ldr r5,=0x000010fc    
str r4,[r5]
```

Is that right way to do?

Comment: Yes, that is what that does.  Is there a particular reason you're unsure?

Comment: Note that these are the so-called *pseudo-instructions* (the first two in your code fragment). ARM Assembler will translate them into the actual ARM opcodes, either a MOV/MVN or (in your case) a PC-relative LDR of a constant from a literal pool. You can read on this [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/pseudo-instructions/ldr-pseudo-instruction?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks, confused with same command writing address and data. I have simulated works fine.